# The transform arrows are binded to the curser and not the object. How do I change this to the object origin?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, transforms

Transform arrows not centered on object origin.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here:

[image: Transform Pivot Point]

Your *Transform Pivot Point* is currently set to *3D Cursor*.
If you want it to be your active-selected object, set it to *Active Element*.
By default, it is set to *Median Point*:

[image: default]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I appreciate it! :D